# Create a data buffer with records of simulink.bus in classdef

Tags: class, properties, simulink

I'm a PLC programmer struggling with Matlab/Simulink. Currently I try to make a new class. Within this class I want a 'DataBuffer' with a length of 5 records of a datatype 'ST_MyRecord'. But I'm struggling with the correct code. The 'MyRecord' is a structure (simulink.bus) definition. This is what I already have:

```
classdef MyClass< matlab.System
    properties (Access = public)
        nIndex uint16 = 0
        DataBuffer ST_MyRecord
    end
    methods (Access = public)
        function obj = mAddRecord(obj)
        end
    end
end
```

Within the PLC world the declaration would be (CoDeSys): `DataBuffer ARRAY[1..5] of ST_MyRecord` how do I create something similar in Matlab/Simulink?

The code above I already tried but got following error:

```
Error defining property 'DataBuffer' of class 'MyClass'. Class named 'ST_MyRecord' is undefined
or does not support property validation. Classes that do not support property validation include
Java, COM classes, and MATLAB classes that do not use the classdef keyword.
```